# How can I configure my tomcat application using server.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I've got a webapp that is deployed in Tomcat.

The webapp uses a `db.properties` file to resolve `dataSource` bean properties in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/db.properties"/>
```

In this example `db.properties` file is placed in common `/conf/` directory of the Tomcat.

And I want to place it not in common `/conf/`, but in a separate subdirectory, like `/conf/myapp/`, and `myapp` should be configured not in application sources, but in Tomcat settings, like `server.xml`.

I need it to deploy two copies of this webapp, but they should work with different databases.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

Here's my `service` block from `server.xml`

```
<Service name="train">
    <Connector port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,text/json,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/json"/>
    <Engine name="trainings" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps">
            <Context docBase="trs" path="" />              
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs/train/int" prefix="access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. place `<context:property-placeholder/>` in applicationContext.xml
2. `<Environment name="db.host" value="localhost" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>` in server.xml in `Context` section
3. just use ${db.host} in the application.